# How to add up a for loop in python

Tags: python

Hello I am working on a problem set in my computer science class and I have encountered a error, Everything seems to work but I cannot seem to figure out exactly how I would approach adding up all the 1, or 0

here is the code

```
    while True:
try:
    num = input("How many times do you want to toss the coin?")
    true = int(num)
    final = True
    if final is True:
        break
except ValueError:
        tebow =("Sorry but this is not a int please try oncce more")
        print (tebow)
for i in range(true):
ok = random.randint(0,1)
print (ok) 
# I am stuck how now I need to add up all the 1's in this case or 2's
```

what this code would do is ask for the user to input how many times they want to toss the coin then it uses random.randomint(0,1) to choose numbers at random what I am trying to do is after it outputs I need to add up the 0's into a variable called tails, and the 1's into a variable called heads, this is where I seem to be stuck. Thank you

Comment: Please fix your indentation first, there is no way this program even runs the way it is currently formatted

Comment: @user3264189 Not like it's shown here, it most certainly does not.

Comment: `final = True; if final is True: break` .. doesn't make much sense in any case.

Comment: There's definitely some strange things in the code. A simple `break` statement would do just fine

Comment: 1. Don't name your variable `true`. Never. 2. Go through your code at least once, line by line and you won't need any help any more. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: I do apologize I am new to programming and evidently have lots to learn I will try and fix my mistakes next time i ask a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you really only need to know how many 1's were produced in N tries.  Because N - (number of 1's) = number of 0's.  Therefore, if you sum all the values returned, that is the number of 1's.  Get it?

```
ones = 0  # first initialize the variable
# put for loop statement here
    ones += random.randint(0,1) # then increment the variable
```

We aren't not going to do this for you, because it is your assignment.  But we can help.

Comment: I am still stuck I get it somewhat but I am trying to figure out how to add up the ones I thought .append might work but it didnt

Comment: Thank you I thought long and hard and with you're help I think I solved this but for some reason my indent works in idle but looks like the one i posted above so I think i will need to fix the indent now but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Even without the proper formatting posted, the answer is basic. You could create two variables to keep track of which number was chosen randomly

```
heads = 0
tails = 0

if ok == 0:
    heads += 1
else:
    tails += 1
```

The operator `+=` is the same as saying `tails = tails + 1`

Comment: However, a more general approach is to use a single array variable; `tosses[ok] += 1` then at the end, loop over `tosses` and print the keys and values.

Comment: I see no point in making things so complicated when there is maximum of only two values.

Comment: Not per se, but it's a common newbie mistake to generalize to dozens of variables when an array or dictionary would be natural, so I think it's worth pointing out.

Comment: Oh I see where you're coming from. Definitely is the solution to go for when there are many variables